# Wordpress filter title

Tags: wordpress, filtering, title

recently I made a question about content filtering which went ok.
Now I'm trying to achieve the same filtering about title, but when it comes to title it doesnt filter only the_title(); but all titles within wp_nav are being filtered. 
The aim is to achieve filtering single post title not the ones within the loop (I know about in_the_loop() )

```
<?php

class Filter_Title {

 public function __construct() {
    if( !is_front_page() && !is_home() && !is_single() ) return;
    if( !is_singular( array('post','page') ) ) return;

    add_filter( 'the_title', array(&$this, 'manage_page_title') );
 }


 public function manage_page_title($title) {

    $title = '';

    return $title;
 }

}

$filtertitle = new Filter_Title();

?>
```

This is my mini plugin class.

Comment: I just tried this and see the issue. I think in the past I have been able to do it with either CSS or one of my hooked themes, which is fine when custom work, not so much when for a plugin.

Comment: Hi topdown, css would not become more dynamic. I'm trying to find a dynamic one. As you say then ppl must define their css selector to post title, which becomes complicated.

Comment: Yeah, I edited my comment. If its for a plugin then CSS would not be the solution. I'll think on it and post an answer if I come up with one.

Comment: Woah man thanks a lot for your responsibility. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tested this and you can match the post_ID with a param to check if its a post.
Since post ids don't match menu ids this should work. Give it a try.

```
function remove_post_title($title, $id) {

    if (is_single() && in_the_loop() && $id == get_the_ID()) {
        $title = '';
    }
    return $title;
}
add_filter('the_title', 'remove_post_title', 10, 2);
```

Note: in a plugin you may need to hook the add_filter in another function and run it in wp_head like before.

Comment: Now you're my man :D thanks a lot for your effort it really did the trick.